# instagram.com mobile version frome iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, instagram, user-agent

i try to access the mobile version of instagram frome iframe using chrome browser on desktop, i tryed change user agent of browser, when i access instagram.com from chrome i get the mobile version of instagram, but from my iframe i get the desktop version.
the code of ifram page is :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="https://www.instagram.com" width="288" height="466" frameborder="0"></iframe<
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That should not work at all, because instagram sends `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` ... (unless you are using an extension in your browser to override this restriction?)

Comment: yes i made an extension to manage that

Comment: And the actual purpose of the exercise is what exactly?

Comment: i wanna show the mobile version of instagram, in thie iframe

Comment: Yes, but _what for_? This is only gonna run in your local browser anyway, so why do you need it? (I am asking because depending on the actual purpose, we might perhaps be able to find alternatives.)

Comment: only curiosity, how instagram mobile version work with the same url of desktop version, facebook use m.facebook, but instagram how it work ?

Comment: Browser sniffing, media queries, ...?

Comment: no, i saw an extension who can do it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/websta-for-instagram/dgkhjjcoidmkfegigfdedmafpfemccpk
but i didn't understand how it work

Comment: Such an extension could easily manipulate the request properties their browser sniffing relies on.

Comment: any idea how it work ?

Comment: Nope ... I’d try browser dev tools first, and see if there are significant differences in the request headers between a “normal” request, and one made using this extension ... (assuming dev tools can actually catch manipulations done by the extension.)

Comment: when i try to use the "toggle device toolbar" of the dev tools, and reload the iframe page, i get the mobile version. i didn't understand why it work on "toggle device toolbar"

Comment: Because Chrome sends different request headers, based on whether you ask it to emulate desktop or mobile …?

Comment: so the question is how to emulate mobile on iframe, i used the user-agent, and reload instagram.com normaly, i got the mobile version, but it don't work with my iframe

Comment: @AlexQuaker Hi Alex,please tell me, have you found the solution?